# How to filter data in VBA?

Tags: arrays, vba

I am working on a AddIn which is based on VBA. I import data from XML file. I want to apply filter on that data. I don't know how can I store and organize data.

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestClass>
  <TestObject>
    <Site>Facebook</Site>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <URL>https://www.facebook.com/ABC/</URL>
  </TestObject>
  <TestObject>
    <Site>Facebook</Site>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <URL>https://www.facebook.com/XYZ/</URL>
  </TestObject>
  <TestObject>
    <Site>Twitter</Site>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <URL>https://www.twitter.com/ABC/</URL>
  </TestObject>
  <TestObject>
    <Site>Facebook</Site>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <URL>https://www.twitter.com/XYZ/</URL>
  </TestObject>
</TestClass>
```

Here is my code.

```
Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFileName = "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\TestFiles\TestData.xml"
oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)

Set Sites = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/Site/text()")
Set Names = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/Name/text()")
Set URLs = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/URL/text()")

Public SiteArray(100) As String 
Public NameArray(100) As String 
Public URLArray(100) As String 

For i = 0 To (Sites.Length - 1)
    SiteArray(i) = Sites(i).NodeValue
    NameArray(i) = Names(i).NodeValue
    URLArray(i) = URLs(i).NodeValue
Next
```

Now I don't know how to get list of `Name` where Site is `Facebook`. I also want to get list of `URL` of `Twitter`.

Can anybody please suggest me mechanism for filtering in above case?

Comment: Your data is currently held in arrays; you will need to loop over them to find what you are looking for.  You might want to consider a 2 dimensional array and store the site, name and url against a single element so everything stays tightly coupled.

Comment: @Dave Can you please suggest me any other way than store in array which is better for filter. I can change my flow accordingly as I just started to work on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you've said you want, I've amended your code and added comments to explain what I'm doing:

```
Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
XMLFileName = "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\TestFiles\TestData.xml"
oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)

Set Sites = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/Site/text()")
Set Names = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/Name/text()")
Set URLs = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/URL/text()")

Public myArray() As String  ' declare array as dynamic so we can amend its size
ReDim myArray(6,0) ' reset it to be 2 dimensional 

For i = 0 To (Sites.Length - 1)
    myArray(0,i) = Sites(i).NodeValue ' Column 1 of the array contains Sites
    myArray(1,i) = Names(i).NodeValue ' Column 2 of the array contains Names
    myArray(2,i) = URLs(i).NodeValue  ' Column 3 of the array contains URLs
    myArray(3,i) = URLs(i).NodeValue  ' Column 4 of the array contains URLs
    myArray(4,i) = URLs(i).NodeValue  ' Column 5 of the array contains URLs
    myArray(5,i) = URLs(i).NodeValue  ' Column 6 of the array contains URLs
    myArray(6,i) = URLs(i).NodeValue  ' Column 7 of the array contains URLs
    ReDim Preserve myArray(6, UBound(myArray,2)+1) ' increase the size of the array dynamically to include an extra "row" of data
Next
' Now you can loop through and search for anything you want, like so:
For i = 0 to UBound(myArray, 2) ' loop through all the "rows" of the array
    If Instr(LCase(myArray(0,i)), "facebook") > 0 Then ' If the site contains facebook
        myName = myArray(1, i) ' returns the associated name for the Site
        myURL = myArray(2, i) ' returns the associated URL for the Site
        ' Do whatever you need with this info then let the loop continue through the rest of the rows or use an Exit For statement to break the loop
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you suggest me for this query? I have tried but didn't find solution. I want to list the `URL` of particular `Name` and particular `Site`. Example. `ABC` can have 2 `Facebook` accounts. So, list the `URL`s whose `Site` is `Facebook` and `Name` is `ABC`

Comment: I mean filter with 2 conditions. "Facebook" and "ABC"

Comment: `If Instr(LCase(myArray(0,i)), "facebook") > 0 And Instr(LCase(myArray(1,i)), "abc") > 0 Then` will check both conditions for you

Comment: I have 7 columns in my case. I will replace 2 with 6 in your code for these lines: 1- Public myArray(2,0) As String. 2- ReDim Preserve myArray(2, UBound(myArray,2)+1). 3- For i = 0 to UBound(myArray, 2). Let me know If I am wrong.

Comment: I've edited the answer to demonstrate the use of 7 columns.  There are still only 2 dimensions to the array (think of them as rows and columns)

Comment: It throws compile time error of `Array is already dimensioned` on this line in above code. `ReDim Preserve myArray(6, UBound(myArray,2)+1)`

Comment: Forgot; the array has to be declared as dynamic in the first instance so that you can adjust its size as required later (although you can only ever increase the final dimension of an array).  See updated answer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114923/discussion-between-nanji-mange-and-dave).

Comment: I can't get to the chat rooms from the office, sorry

Comment: I am not able to read the XML file. I could read before but I don't know why it is not working now. It loaded but not able to read. I have posted a different question with example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37877170/not-able-to-get-data-from-xml-file-in-vba