# Not able to get data from XML file in VBA?

Tags: xml, vba

I am trying to get data from XML file but can't get. I don't know what I am missing here.

XML File:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TestClass>
  <TestObject>
    <Site>Facebook</Site>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <URL>https://www.facebook.com/ABC/</URL>
  </TestObject>
  <TestObject>
    <Site>Facebook</Site>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <URL>https://www.facebook.com/XYZ/</URL>
  </TestObject>
  <TestObject>
    <Site>Twitter</Site>
    <Name>ABC</Name>
    <URL>https://www.twitter.com/ABC/</URL>
  </TestObject>
  <TestObject>
    <Site>Facebook</Site>
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <URL>https://www.twitter.com/XYZ/</URL>
  </TestObject>
</TestClass>
```

Code:

```vb
Dim oXMLFile As Object
 Dim XMLFileName As String
 Dim Sites As Object
 Dim Names As Object
 Dim URLs As Object

 Set oXMLFile = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
 XMLFileName = "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Files\Test.xml"
 oXMLFile.Load (XMLFileName)
 If oXMLFile.Load(XMLFileName) Then
   ' The document successfully to load.
Else
   ' The document failed to load.
End If

Sites = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/Site/text()")
Names = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/Name/text()")
URLs = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/URL/text()")
```

In above case `Sites`, `Names` and `URLs` gets nothing.
[image]
Can anybody suggest me if I am missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Sites`, `Names`and `URLs` are `Object`, you need to use the`Set` keyword.

```
Set Sites = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/Site/text()")
Set Names = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/Name/text()")
Set URLs = oXMLFile.SelectNodes("TestClass/TestObject/URL/text()")
```

I'm surprised you didn't get an error, but it may be because `Object` are specials.

Since `SelectNodes` returns a `IXMLDOMNodeList`, you might want to replace your definitions by:

```
Dim oXMLFile as DOMDocument
Dim Sites As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim Names As IXMLDOMNodeList
Dim URLs As IXMLDOMNodeList
```

Answer (score 1):

Try xml linq

```
Imports System.Xml
Imports System.Xml.Linq
Module Module1
    Const FILENAME As String = "c:\temp\test.xml"
    Sub Main()
        Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load(FILENAME)

        Dim results = doc.Descendants("TestObject").Select(Function(x) New With { _
            .site = CType(x.Element("Site"), String), _
            .name = CType(x.Element("Name"), String), _
            .url = CType(x.Element("URL"), String) _
        }).ToList()
    End Sub

End Module
```